# Flash of Unstyled Content when reloading page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

First, let me say that it only seems to be Chrome that has this specific issue. Everything works flawlessly in IE. (Firefox has a little bit of something weird going on but I am really only concerned with Chrome at this point.)

Second, I am doing this in Django, hence the `{% template tags %}` in the html.

I am trying to make a "night mode" button on my website. It is all working great until I reload the page or go to another page on the site. At those times, I get a Flash of Unstyled Content and I have no idea how to fix it.

I already moved my `<script>`s to `<head>` so they would load faster, even though I know best practice is to but them right before `</body>`.

I have seen a few posts recommending hiding the html until the page is fully loaded but I just ended up with an even longer flash of a blank page so I am thinking that's not the option I would prefer.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with most of the features of Dev Tools. If anyone has pointers on how to use that to track what's going on, I would really appreciate that.

I'm wondering if anyone has any other ideas. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<head> ...

    <title>{% block title %}Portfolio{% endblock %}</title>

    {% load staticfiles %}

    <link id="bootstrap-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/4-alpha/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/main.css' %}">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/cfcc69be16.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'home/js/navbar.js' %}"></script>

</head>

<body>
    ...
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="change-theme">Change Theme</button>


    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>
```

JS:

```
function storageAvailable(type) {
    try {
        var storage = window[type],
            x = '__storage_test__';
        storage.setItem(x, x);
        storage.removeItem(x);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return e instanceof DOMException && (
            // everything except Firefox
            e.code === 22 ||
            // Firefox
            e.code === 1014 ||
            // test name field too, because code might not be present
            // everything except Firefox
            e.name === 'QuotaExceededError' ||
            // Firefox
            e.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') &&
            // acknowledge QuotaExceededError only if there's something already stored
            storage.length !== 0;
    }
}


if (storageAvailable("localStorage")) {
    var activeTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

    if (activeTheme == null) {
        localStorage.setItem("theme", $("#bootstrap-css").attr("href"));
        activeTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    }

    $("#bootstrap-css").attr("href", activeTheme);
}
else {
    alert("Please activate local storage in your browser to use this funtion.");
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    var flatly = "https://bootswatch.com/4-alpha/flatly/bootstrap.min.css";
    var darkly = "https://bootswatch.com/4-alpha/darkly/bootstrap.min.css";

    $("#change-theme").on("click", function() {
        if (activeTheme == flatly) {
            $("#bootstrap-css").attr("href", darkly);
            localStorage.setItem("theme", darkly);
            activeTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
        }
        else {
            $("#bootstrap-css").attr("href", flatly);
            localStorage.setItem("theme", flatly);
            activeTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Make sure the `#bootstrap-css` element is before this script. Try inlining the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting these 2 into  tags in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/4-alpha/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/4-alpha/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and remove the vars from the JS